# BuildCircleMbr with 1km of accuracy - spatialite

Tags: spatialite

I want to create a Circle MBR in spatialite of 1km for example from lat/lon in WGS84

I use `BuildCircleMBR` but i am not able to generate this well.

My query
`SELECT BuildCircleMbr(40.0,-4.0,1, 1000)`

I have read the third argument (1000) should be in degrees and not in meters but i don't know how to do this.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done so straight with Spatialite in WGS84 lat/lon because BuildCircleMbr does not take into account that Earth is round. You can set the last argument to degrees and you can even calculate that one degree corresponds to 111.045 km when you move along the longitudes in S-N direction and thus 1 km = 0.0090053 degrees. However, the closer to the poles you are the shorter is the distance between the longitudes in W-E direction. See for example http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm

The result of SELECT BuildCircleMbr(40.0,-40, 0.0090053) gives you a box with 1 km offset to North and South but because to point is at latitude -40S the offset to West and East is only about 766 meters.

For getting your 1 x 1 km box I believe you must utilize the ST_Distance function http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. The function returns distances between geometries along the great circle or WGS84 ellipsoid depending if the last parameter is 0 or 1. You must build something around the function yourself for resolving the unknown target coordinate when you know the start coordinate and distance. In the next SQL I used pure trial-and-error iteration for resolving the desired longitude **-40.008999**.

```
SELECT st_distance(geomfromtext('POINT (40 -40)',4326),geomfromtext('POINT (40 -40.008999)',4326),0) as gc_distance;

gc_distance
===========
1000.644523
```

I suppose that you know that the result of BuildCircleMbr is a box, not a circle as I believed in the beginning.

```
SELECT astext(BuildCircleMbr(40.0,-40, 0.0090053)) as mbr;

mbr
=== 
POLYGON((39.990995 -40.009005, 40.009005 -40.009005, 40.009005 -39.990995, 39.990995 -39.990995, 39.990995 -40.009005))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the distance like this:

```sql
SELECT distance(GeomFromText("POINT(40.0 -4.0)", 4326), ST_Project(GeomFromText("POINT(40.0 -4.0)", 4326), 1000, 0))
```

You use `distance` to compute the degrees between your source point and a point you projected 1000 meters away from it using `ST_Project`.